# Change each regression line styling using in a multiple regressions plot Python

Tags: python, regression, seaborn, lmplot

I am currently trying to plot two regression lines for my data split by a categorical attribute (which is either freedom or happiness scores). My current qualm is that I need color to encode another separate categorical attribute in my graph (GNI/capita brackets). Having a mix of colors seemed confusing so I decided to distinguish the data points using different markers instead. However, I am having trouble changing just one of the regression lines to a dashed line as they are identical. I don't even want to think about how I am going to create a legend for all of this. If you think this is an ugly graph, I agree, but certain circumstances mandate I have four attributes encoded in a single graph. By the way, open to any suggestions at all on a better way to do this - if there is any. An example of my current graph is below and would appreciate any help!

```
sns.lmplot(data=combined_indicators, x='x', y='y', hue='Indicator', palette=["#000620"], markers=['x', '.'], ci=None)
plt.axvspan(0,1025, alpha=0.5, color='#de425b', zorder=-1)
plt.axvspan(1025,4035, alpha=0.5, color='#fbb862', zorder=-1)
plt.axvspan(4035,12475, alpha=0.5, color ='#afd17c', zorder=-1)
plt.axvspan(12475,100000, alpha=0.5, color='#00876c', zorder=-1)
plt.title("HFI & Happiness Regressed on GNI/capita")
plt.xlabel("GNI/Capita by Purchasing Power Parity (2017 International $)")
plt.ylabel("Standard Indicator Score (0-10)")
```

[My current figure rears its ugly head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyUOk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no easy way to change the style of the regression line in `lmplot`. But you can achieve your goal if you use `regplot` instead of `lmplot`, the drawback being that you have to implement the `hue`-splitting "by hand"

```
x_col = 'total_bill'
y_col = 'tip'
hue_col = 'smoker'
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

markers = ['x','.']
colors = ["#000620", "#000620"]
linestyles = ['-','--']

plt.figure()
for (hue,gr),m,c,ls in zip(df.groupby(hue_col),markers,colors,linestyles):
    sns.regplot(data=gr, x=x_col, y=y_col, marker=m, color=c, line_kws={'ls':ls}, ci=None, label=f'{hue_col}={hue}')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, if anyone stumbled upon this post later, you can create a legend for this mess manually using Line2D. Looks something like this for mine:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color='#000620', lw=2, label='Freedom', linestyle='--'),
                   Line2D([0],[0], color='#000620', lw=2, label='Happiness'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='x', color='#000620', label='Freedom',
                          markerfacecolor='#000620', markersize=15),
                   Line2D([0], [0], marker='.', color='#000620', label='Happiness',
                          markerfacecolor='#000620', markersize=15),
                   Patch(facecolor='#de425b', label='Low-Income'),
                   Patch(facecolor='#fbb862', label='Lower Middle-Income'),
                   Patch(facecolor='#afd17c', label='Upper Middle-Income'),
                   Patch(facecolor='#00876c', label='High-Income')]
```

The end result looks like this:
[Graph with custom legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNNCI.png)